# I have an issue trying to work with mongoose Schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I have an issue with the mongoose schema class, where it says the method expression is not of function type.

Here's the code itself

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const travelOrderSchema = mongoose.Schema ({

});

exports.TravelOrder = mongoose.model('TravelOrder', travelOrderSchema);
```

It was to be used as a model like so...

```js
const { TravelOrder } = require('../models/travelorder');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get(`/`, async (req, res) => {
    const travelOrderList = await TravelOrder.find();

    if (!travelOrderList) {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false });
    }

    res.send(travelOrderList);
})

module.exports = router;
```

But it stops at the reqire statement with the message
"at Object. (../FILE_PATH//travelorders.js:1:25)"

Comment: Can you provide more information about the error. 

The `find` method should be called with an empty object if you are not filtering the data {}

Comment: You might try `module.exports = {TravelOrder: mongoose.model('TravelOrder', travelOrderSchema)};`